# Read JSON with HttpClient, REST and gzip

Tags: java, rest, gzip

I'm trying to call a rest service using HttpClient, POST method.
The service returns a json using gzip compression.
The json in response for some reason is not associated with the string variable "output" which is always empty in the logs. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FSus.png)
In debug I can only see the initial value of the json. The result of entity.getContent() is org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@30f5a68a.
The same test through SoapUI seems fine.

Java Code

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(endpoint);
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");         
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonRequest));
        
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();
                CloseableHttpResponse res = httpClient.execute(httpPost)) {

            HttpEntity entity = res.getEntity();
            LOG.debug(entity.getContent());
                
            if (entity != null) {

                String output = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
                LOG.debug(output); // <------- empty LOG
            }

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            LOG.error(exc);
        }
```

Maven

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

SAOP UI Request

```
POST https://host HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 2627
Host: host
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

SAOP UI Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 26 May 2021 08:48:57 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
X-Backside-Transport: OK OK
Content-Type: application/json
X-Global-Transaction-ID: dc640eac60ae0b794b55bcaf
APIHttpStatus: 200
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=65
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"ShipmentResponse":{"Response":{"ResponseStatus":{"Code":"1", "Description":"Success"}, "Alert":[{"Code":"120900", "Description":"User Id ...
```

[Soap UI Json view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsYQv.png)

Comment: Notice Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Answer (score 0):

Use the string from `entity.getContent()`

```
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(entity.getContent()));
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));
    String outStr = "";
    String line;
    while ((line=bf.readLine())!=null) {
      outStr += line;
    }
    System.out.println("Output String lenght : " + outStr.length());
```

Edit:

There seems to be an entity wrapper for gzipped content:
https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/latest/org/apache/http/client/entity/GzipDecompressingEntity.html

```
(new GzipDecompressingEntity(entity)).getContent()
```

Comment: With
GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(entity.getContent());
i get:
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
P.S. getContent returns an InputStream

Comment: Also with this code I get an full EMPTY log line:
[code]
Reader decoder = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8");
BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(decoder);
final String line = buffered.readLine();
LOG.debug(line);
[code]

Comment: and you can see the service logs that it is returning some json?

Comment: After Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Server returns a compressed stream: "[0x1f][0x8b][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x3][0xac][0xb9][0xd7][0xce] (and so on). This is the json string

Comment: nice! how you tried using

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/latest/org/apache/http/client/entity/GzipDecompressingEntity.html

==>    (new GzipDecompressingEntity(entity)).getContent()

Comment: GzipDecompressingEntity gde = new GzipDecompressingEntity(entity);
                  InputStream content = gde.getContent();
                  String output = IOUtils.toString(content, "UTF-8");

IOUtils.String() returns java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format